# What are the rules regarding importing sweets from the USA into Sweden as an individual?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, eu, sweden

I'm going back to Sweden from a trip to the USA, and I'm wondering what the rules are regarding bringing sweets back to Sweden. I've found an EU document detailing what you are allowed to import[1] with regards to food, but it does not make it clear to me whether packaged sweets are okay. If I'm reading it right, sweets would fall under "ex 2106" in part 2 of annex I, which would mean that sweets only are okay if they don't contain any milk or meat. Is this correct? It seems needlessly limiting to me given that I would think of sweets as low-risk food in terms of containing disease.

Am I reading this right, i.e., are sweets only okay if they don't contain any milk or meat, or am I missing something?

- [1] https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg_del/2019/2122/oj/eng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the Swedish government](https://www.government.se/government-of-sweden/ministry-for-foreign-affairs/diplomatic-portal/diplomatic-guide/13.-customs-privileges-and-duty-free-import/13.5-restrictions/):

> In general, the import of meat and dairy products to Sweden from non-EU countries is not allowed. Exceptions are made if you import food from Andorra, Liechtenstein, Norway, San Marino or Switzerland.
>
> The following foodstuffs can be imported without restriction:
>
> - Bread, biscuits, chocolate and sweets, unless mixed with or filled with meat products
> - ...
>
> For more detailed information contact the [Swedish Board of Agriculture (Jordbruksverket)](http://www.jordbruksverket.se/swedishboardofagriculture.4.6621c2fb1231eb917e680002462.html) or [Swedish Customs](https://www.tullverket.se/en/startpage.4.a62602917de14e432714e9.html).

So if your sweets contain some dairy in them (e.g., milk chocolate or an enriched dough), you should be okay, but not if they contain meat. You can contact the agencies linked above if you still have a question, or present your goods for inspection at the "something to declare" (red) customs channel upon arrival for an official opinion. I do not know Sweden's policies specifically, but in most countries, if you are up front about it but the goods are not allowed (and are not something truly illegal like narcotics), it is likely that they would be seized and destroyed but you would face no further trouble.